# Loading a queue?

Tags: 7, drush, queue

How can I use [Drush](https://drupal.org/project/drush) to pass data into a [Drupal Queue](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.queue.inc/group/queue/7)?

```
function hook_cron_queue_info() {
  $queues['my_queue_name'] = array(
    'worker callback' => '_my_queue_callback', // This is the callback function for each queue item.
    'time' => 25, // This is the max run time per cron run in seconds.
  );
  return $queues;
}

function module_name_load_queue($item) {
  $queue = DrupalQueue::get('my_queue_name');
  $queue->createItem(json_encode($item));
}
```

My ultimate goal is to pre-process data using a few bash scripts and then pass the end result to `module_name_load_queue($item);` using Drush.

Is this possible? If so, how do I go about this?

Answer (score 0):

Yes We can use drush queue run to initiate a queue

**Example :**

```
#!/bin/sh
SLEEP=${2} #Make the sleep time as configurable
while true
do
   drush5 --uri=${1} queue-run <Your QUEUE NAME> #${1} Domain URI
   sleep ${SLEEP}
done
```

Comment: I'm looking to load (fill) a queue using drush rather than start a queue. Thank you though as this will be useful in the next step.

Answer (score 0):

The most common practice is to create a custom cron job that populates the queue. Failing that you could use drush ev "my_callback()" to accomplish this.